# Include 'regular' .php file in symlinked .php file

Tags: php, symlink, require

So, I have a project with config files. When I deploy my code, I don't want the config files of individual servers to be overwritten, do I made a symlink that points to /var/www/config/config.php. That works fine.

Now the problem: config.php requires other .php files, which I do want to deploy. E.g. they're not in /var/www/config, they're in the folder where the symlink sits (/var/www/project/global/config/whatever).

Can I somehow require from the path the symlink is in, instead of the path the symlinked config.php is in?

So basically I want /var/www/config/config.php to include /var/www/project/global/config/file.php when I say require('file.php').

I.e., online separate the one config.php from the codebase, not everything it uses.

How can that be done?

Comment: How is config.php being included? If you're including the symlink, the paths should all be relative to the source file.

Comment: It's being included via require_once('config/config.php') from php files in the global, and via 'global/config/config.php' from project folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Set includes path in PHP

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/var/www/project/global/config/whatever');
```